# Kill inactive user sessions on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Terminal server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I've been trying to configure a GPO to kill inactive sessions on a Windows Server 2012 R2 terminal server, but I can't seem to be able to get it done.

I went to *Computer Settings* → *Policies* → *Admin templates* → *Windows Components* → *Remote Desktop Services* → *RD Session Host* → *Session Time Limits* and configured:

1. Set time limit for domain controller sessions → 30 minutes
2. Set time limit for active but idle sessions → 30 minutes
3. End session when time limits are reached → Enabled

I've checked and made sure the policy is applying to the server in question by running `gpresult /r /scope:computer`.

The problem is that, after 30 minutes, the user sessions that are inactive are still not killed, and they sit there in a disconnected state using memory resources that they shouldn't.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

Gah...I'm sorry, I didn't check your question correctly...Terminal Services *are* Remote Desktop Services now since Windows Server 2008 R2 (I think). Sorry!

Check your RDS settings on the server itself - not GPO -, under

> Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration

(`override user settings`) and try specifying the time limits there.

<del>Check the following GPO settings:</del>

<del>> Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows</del> 
 <del>> Components\Terminal Services\Terminal Server\Session Time Limits</del>

<del>Your GPO settings are only for RDP sessions, not for Terminal Server sessions.</del>

Comment: For some reason I'm unable to see Terminal Services under Windows Components, am I missing a feature or something? Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have the Remote Desktop Services role installed?

Comment: Yes, I do have the RDS role installed, but only the Session Host feature on this server on which I'm trying to kill the sessions

Comment: I still can't find the RD Session Host console where the Session settings are, but that's just me and the fact that I don't have any documentation on these servers, so configuration-wise I don't know how the roles have been separated, but yes your answer should do the trick if applied correctly.